# Error reading .xsession-errors

Tags: 16.04

I am having trouble reading .xsession-errors
I have tried `~/.xsession-errors` and `cat ~/.xsession-errors`

All result in permission denied

I use Ubuntu 16.04

When I type this command in...

```
namei -l ~/.xsession-errors
```

This is the output...

```
f: /home/mikulis/.xsession-errors
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root home
drwx——— mikulis mikulis mikulis
-rw———- root root .xsession-errors
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `namei -l ~/.xsession-errors`

Comment: What does it all mean? How do we fix it?

Comment: It *seems* to indicate that the file is owned and only readable by `root` (usually a result of doing something ill-advised like `sudo startx`) while the directories above are OK. However that should mean that `sudo cat ~/.xsession-errors` would work, so perhaps there's something else wrong? Regardless, start by trying to fix the ownership i.e. `sudo chown mikulis:mikulis ~/.xsession-errors` and report back please

Comment: `Sudo cat ~/.xsession-errors` results in `Xsession: X session started for root localuser:root being added to access control list openConnection: connect: no such file or directory cannot connect to brltty at :0`

Comment: I also found another xsessions file .xsession-errors.old and when I `cat xsession-errors.old` I receive `upstart: Failed to write to log file /home/mikulis/.cache/upstart/unity7.log`